# Property progid doesn't exist : DXImageTransform

Tags: css, validation

This is CSS Code and CSS Validator saying Property progid doesn't exist : `DXImageTransform` and also

```
Parse Error DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2a65a9', endColorstr='#0c407d',GradientType=0 );    
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2a65a9', endColorstr='#0c407d',GradientType=0 );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter property only used for IE and to validate this code put it in "IE conditional comments" example below.

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
```